What is the difference between a Ubuntu server install vs a Ubuntu desktop install that is set to boot into systemd multi.user.target?
I am using Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 LTS.
To set Ubuntu to boot into "text-mode" as i call it (r̶u̶n̶l̶e̶v̶e̶l̶3̶.t̶a̶r̶g̶e̶t̶/multi-user.target):
I use sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
As for the question:
I know that the Desktop ISO file of Ubuntu is larger, since it has a desktop environment that needs more dependencies in order to function properly.
But do the same processes run in the Desktop edition when booting into multi.user.target than on a boot with the server edition of Ubuntu?

Run levels don't exist anymore since systemd. Looking at the output of ls -l /usr/lib/systemd/system/runlevel*  runlevel 2,3,4 all point to multi-user.target

Thanks for the clarification.
